# Using polling with isDone and Cancel on Java Future instead of blocking get

Tags: java, multithreading, future

I am working on some legacy code which I can not refactor immediately.

The code uses blocking Java Future. It uses future.get(withTimeOut,...). This, means that we need to have a decent size thread pool to be responsive enough. As the calls will get blocked till they finish or times out.

Question:
I was thinking to grab the future and put it in a data structure which will be aware of start of execution of a task. Then have a dedicated thread or pool which will loop over the data structure and check if the future.isDone or has exceeded timeout limit. If yes, it can either get the result or cancel the execution. This way not many threads would be required. Will it be a correct implementation or it is not recommended at all?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Just to provide more context. These threads are used for logging to a downstream service. We really do not care about the response but we do not want the connection to hung. Thus, we need to grab the future and ensure that it is cancelled or timed out.

Here is a basic simulation which I wrote after asking the question.

```
@Component
public class PollingService {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    PoorMultiplexer poorMultiplexer = new PoorMultiplexer();
    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Map<Future, Long>> futures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void startHandler(){
        Thread handler = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        //This should be handled better. If there is not anything stop and re-start it later.
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    for(Iterator<ConcurrentMap.Entry<Integer, Map<Future, Long>>> it = futures.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();){
                        ConcurrentMap.Entry<Integer, Map<Future, Long>> entry = it.next();
                        Map<Future, Long> futureMap = entry.getValue();
                        boolean isProcessed = false;
                        if(futureMap.keySet().iterator().next().isDone()){
                            //mark completed
                            isProcessed = true;
                        }

                        if(futureMap.values().iterator().next() < (300 + System.currentTimeMillis()) && !isProcessed){
                            //cancel
                            futureMap.keySet().iterator().next().cancel(true);
                            isProcessed = true;
                        }

                        if(isProcessed){
                            futures.remove(entry.getKey());
                            System.out.println("Completed : " + entry.getKey());
                        }

                    }

                    System.out.println("Run completed");
                }
            }
        });

        handler.start();
    }

    public void run(int i) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        System.out.println("Starting : " + i);

        poorMultiplexer.send(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Future future = poorMultiplexer.send(execute());

                Map<Future, Long> entry = new HashMap<>();
                entry.put(future, startTime);
                futures.put(i, entry);
                System.out.println("Added : " + i);
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop(){
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public Runnable execute(){
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        return worker;
    }
}


//This is a placeholder for a framework
class PoorMultiplexer {
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

    public Future send(Runnable task){
        return executorService.submit(task);
    }
}


class Worker implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //service call here
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your question is too broad; when asking for design help, answers are typically "opinions"; as any solution has its pros and cons. And to be really precise: we can't say if your implementation will be **correct**. From 10000 feet above your idea sounds reasonable; but then again: we don't have much details. It might be better to sketch a bit of UML ... and then talk to your peers who know the application and get their input. Asking other people that really don't know your code about which change makes sense ... simply can't result in great ansers.

Comment: @Jägermeister I feel it is a general problem with blocking calls. I have implemented a sample after asking here, it seems to work but need further handling. You are correct, I should have provided more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronously polling a set of Futures using a separate thread does sound like a reasonable implementation to me. That said, if you're able to add a library dependency, you might find it easier to switch to Guava's [ListenableFuture](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained), as Guava provides a wealth of utilities for doing asynchronous work.

Comment: Yes, I read through few of these things but unfortunately it will be difficult to add them. Thanks for your response.